# Why don't CAs advertize public keys of verified entities on a central location instead of giving out signed certificates?

Tags: encryption, tls, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, man-in-the-middle

If CAs (Certification Authorities) start advertizing public keys of verified websites via some API, browsers can simply query them for each domain instead of asking websites to give them certificates signed by CAs. If malicious entities try to intercept traffic and do the TLS handshake, they'll fail because they won't have the corresponding private key required to complete the process.

What's the reason why this method is not preferred?

*Edit:* The advantage of this an API-based method might be that that the entire process of creating a CSR, getting it signed from a CA by paying them, installing all the intermediary certificates on your server, and then handing it to the client on each request might be avoided.

Comment: This would create a huge load on the CA's servers.  Also, if the CA's servers are unreachable, this could potentially be a single point of failure for a large number of sites.

Comment: In addition, there are privacy concerns. In such cases, CAs would be able to collect very detailed usage statistics of every web site CA issue certificates to.

Comment: What about self signed certs used in companies?How would you implement that then?

Comment: Load on servers can be managed, I guess similar to what happens in DNS servers. Usage statistics would be limited to how many times a browser (or its servers) call that website, and that is perhaps not that big of a concern given the advantages. Self-signed certificate can be alternatively handled via browsers inside the organization trusting the organization's CA to publish public keys of internal servers

Comment: This would also add a round-trip to the CA to every new connection and require perfect uptime and low latency from all CAs. This online validation is why [CRLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_revocation_list#Problems_with_CRLs_(Certificate_revocation_list)) have failed. Using it to replace certificates would negate the entire point of public key infrastructure. And no, you can't just say "load can be managed" at that scale. Also: how would I get a secure connection to the CA if I need to talk to a CA to get its public key? You've also failed to describe the "advantages" you mention.

Comment: @Marc I was thinking that DNS servers also are supposed to be up and live at all times. Whichever way helped them to achieve this, might be able to help in this case too. No? Caching can also be used. For the 2nd point, that might pose a problem with man-in-the-middle attacks. Advantage is foregoing the entire process of raisng a CSR, getting yourself verified, all the certificate chains, and all that. But I guess securing the connection to the CA might be a deal-breaker

Comment: What's the problem this solves that isn't already solved? HSTS forbids accepting certificates that aren't signed by a trusted CA. That's a solution that doesn't create new problems like your suggestion, as explained in the comments.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. If you want to ask about alternatives to PKI infrastructure, you need to list the problems you want to address and show what your proposal would improve.

Comment: @Marc The question was about why a particular API-based model won't be feasible. I don't need to list down advantages of my system when I'm asking for why the alternate is not feasible. I specifically stated reasons why I thought it *could* be feasible. As answer, the point about securing the connection to the CA should be mentioned as to why its not feasible. The question is perfectly valid and shouldn't be closed.

Comment: If you take a quick gander at [how to ask a good question](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), you'll see that you're missing a few things: 1) you did no research or if you did, you're not showing it. 2) this is not specific at all and despite our requests you haven't clarified anything 3) this is pretty open-ended as it has to do with the design choices for a PKI. This is a 40 year long discussion.

Comment: This question is actually more interesting in the context of *certificate revocation*.  Initially, we had CRL, which relied heavily on CA servers.  Then, to shift the load off of CA servers, and on to sites' servers, we now have OCSP.

Comment: @Marc 1) I tried but couldn't find anything relevant to "api-based certificate authority" 2) I did specify the advantages of the alternate approach when you asked in the comments (have added them in the question now) 3) There doesn't seem to be any rule against posting questions about design choices. [Here](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) it says that subjective questions can be asked.

Anyways, you asked about how to get a secure conection to CA if I'm receving all public keys from it? Browsers can come pre-installed with public keys of trusted CAs like certs come today

Comment: Ok then, I've retracted my flag. I'll give this a stab when I'm back at a computer for a decent amount of time, unless of course someone beats me to it.